# how to fetch and store integer value inside (...) in a cell in excel to a variable using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read integer values 10, 12, 2 from the second column of the excel sheet and store it to variables using python.

provided link to the png image representing cells in excel sheet

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/82por.png]

Using below code I'm able to read the entire data - `Parrot(10)` whereas i want integer value of `10`

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd

# Load csv
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

abc = df['Birds'].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd

# Load csv
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

word = df['Birds'].iloc[0]
offset = word.find("(")
num = word[offset+1:-1]
```

This is finding the index of the opening bracket
then adding 1 to find the first number
then ignoring the closing bracket but only going to -1

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is actually 'how do I extract the number from a mixed string of numbers and letters' you probably want a regex.

```py
import re
cell = "Parrot(10)"
matches = re.search(r"([0-9]+)", cell)
number = int(matches.group(1))
```

There are other approaches, but this is probably the simplest for the dataset in question.

### References

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: above code works, but it is giving only the last digit.

If it is Parrot(235) , output i'm getting is only last digit '5' . But i wanted integer value 235.

Could you please tell me what is the significance of using `.group(1)` here?

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case you can use list comprehension and join function.

**Code:**

```
abc = "Parrot(10)"
number = int("".join([ch for ch in abc if ch.isdigit()]))
print(number)
```